# Stuck merging two dataframes, getting unexpected results

Tags: pandas

Thank you, I only 3 weeks into learning Pandas, and I am getting unexpected results, any guidance would be appreciated.

I would like to merge two DataFrames together and retain my `set_index`.

I have a simple DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'part_number': [123,123,123],
    'part_name': ['some name in 11', 'some name in 12', 'some name in 13'],
    'part_size': [11,12,13]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.set_index('part_name', inplace=True)
```

[image]

I groupby the part_sizes, and merge.

This is where my knowledge breaks down, I lose my index which is the part_name.

I see there are joins and concats, am I using the wrong syntax?

```
part_size_merge = df.groupby(['part_number'], dropna=False)['part_size'].agg(tuple).to_frame()
merged = df.merge(part_size_merge, on=['part_number'])
display(merged.head())
```

[image]

I tried concat, however, it looks like it stacks the two df's together, which isn't how I'd like it.

```
x = pd.concat([df, part_size_merge], axis=0, join='inner')
x.head()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is normal `merge`

```
out = df.reset_index().merge(part_size_merge, on=['part_number']).set_index('part_name')
Out[334]: 
                 part_number  part_size_x   part_size_y
part_name                                              
some name in 11          123           11  (11, 12, 13)
some name in 12          123           12  (11, 12, 13)
some name in 13          123           13  (11, 12, 13)
```

Comment: thank you, this works! Can I check something with you please? Why do you reset the index before the merge?

Comment: @dimButTries cause merge will reset the index , nad you will get a new index for range 0 - n , so we reset_index to keep the original index , then set it back